# How to Change Live Broadcast in control Bar in jWplayer 7

Tags: live, broadcast, jwplayer7

I need to change the text "Live Broadcast" in my live Streaming with title of the Live stream. How can i achieved this. I am newer in jwplayer. Any help would be appreciatable.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Are you seeing this in the player or as part of the stream? You can add a title to your source when you set up a player.

```
<div id="myElement">Loading the player...</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
var playerInstance = jwplayer("myElement");
playerInstance.setup({
    file: "//example.com/uploads/myVideo.mp4",
    title: 'Basic Video Embed',
    description: 'A video with a basic title and description!',
});
</script>
```

https://support.jwplayer.com/customer/en/portal/articles/1406723-basic-video-embed

Comment: "Live Broadcast" Text is displayed at the control bar at left side. I want to remove or change that text. Title is displayed either in left or right side of jwplayer.

Comment: Thanks for reply me.

Comment: I would recommend opening up a support case (support at jwplayer dot com) -- it's hard to troubleshoot this without seeing your code.